# How to redirect browser from POST request to GET a new location? servlet

Tags: google-app-engine, browser, servlets, redirect

I'm using GAE with Java servlets.
I have a form POST request, and I have to redirect the browser to a new location with GET method. How can I do this?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got solution:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

This is my code sample:

```
private void seeOther(HttpServletResponse resp, String pathOfOtherToSee)
{
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_SEE_OTHER);
    resp.setHeader("Location", pathOfOtherToSee);       
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much the standard way. Would you care to show us the code to do this w/ Java servlet?